# Value not expanded in Angular templating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to understand the basics of angularJS and I test expanding template, because we have some issues with microtemplating we use before.

Please take a look to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V6e23/)

there is this line: `<span ng-click="foo('{{item.id}}', '{{item.name}}')">{{item.name}}</span>`

when I look via chrome inspector, it was expanded as expected: `<span ng-click="foo('1', 'name1')" class="ng-binding">name1</span>`

but the click alerts: `{{item.id}}` and `{{item.name}}` unexpanded.

where is the point I'm going wrong? What I have misunderstand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your **foo** function , you are passing strings.
Try this `<span ng-click="foo(item.id, item.name)">{{item.name}}</span>`

:)

Answer (score 1):

In Angular, interpolation is handled separately from directives, at a lower priority.

So what's happening is the `ng-click` directive is handled first; it parses `"foo('{{item.id}}', '{{item.name}}')"` without interpolation.
Then, the interpolation is handled, which updates the raw `ng-click` attribute to `"foo('1', 'name1')"`.

However, since `ng-click` already parsed the expression, it doesn't parse it again after interpolation changes.  So that's why `ng-click` doesn't get the updated values.

As @Tedmosby said, the correct way to handle this behavior is to avoid using interpolation within a directive.